# Xcode - ITMS errors (90022, 90023, 90704)

Tags: swift, xcode

Iam trying to upload my app but I get the error codes 90022, 90023 and 90704. App icons are on the assets and all necessary keys are referenced on the info.plist file.

You can check them here :

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yblRw.png)

[Assests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgxoC.png)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei2UF.jpg)

Maybe I'm missing a key value on the info.plist file or I need to erase like a "cache" or "derived data" folder.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Your AppIcon screenshot has too little images. I would suggest creating a new AppIcon file it will have twice the sizes you see there.

This particular file is likely missing the required sizes as the error says.